# logical error in my python code, compiler show nothing

Tags: python, compiler-errors

hello my compiler must show 5 but says press any key to continue means nothing. can you solve my problem?

```
def result(num1,num2):
    num3 = num1+num2
    return num3
    print(result(3,2))
```

Comment: This isn't a compiler error, so please don't use that tag. `return`ing in a function ends its execution and returns control to the caller. Your `print()` will never run.

Comment: You may also remove the indentation before `print(result(3, 2))` to get correct result. This is, let's say, a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function call `print(result(3,2))` is inside the function `result` after `return` (which also means it will never be reached). Simply move it out of the function

```
def result(num1,num2):
    num3 = num1+num2
    return num3

print(result(3,2)) # 1 Identation back
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as compiler in python :)
2. Indentation is a part of syntax, your `print` became a part of function
   You can try this

   ```
    def result(num1,num2):
      num3 = num1+num2
      return num3

    print(result(3,2))
   ```